# Term for anything above a limit

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

I have a following write up and I feel there is a room to improvise on the usage of words to better deliver the message:

> This will allow a maximum of 40 batches per second. If the rate exceeds 40 then the "overdue" order will result error.

What can be a better term for overdue?

"word in quote needs to be improvised"

Comment: You've already said _if the rate exceeds_ so just: _If the rate exceeds 40 then the order will result in an error._ or  _An error will result if the rate exceeds 40._

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It sounds like you question may be a [single-word-request]. Should this be the case, please adjust your sample sentence to show which word you are looking to replace.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I mean to say 41st and onwards order will result in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**overage**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overage)

> A surplus; an excess.

As in:

> If the rate exceeds 40, the **overage** will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

A replacement might be; 
"If the rate exceeds 40 then the excess will result in an error."
Or "If the rate exceeds 40 it will cause an error." 
or "If the rate exceeds 40 then an error will occur."

"Overdue" is cannot be correct here except as a place holder.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Please provide sources and/or reasoning for your answer to improve its quality.